# SKLearn Boston dataset gradient descent not working

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, gradient-descent, implementation

I am trying to compare some simple methods for linear regression as an exercise.

I have already used LinearRegression from the SKLearn library in python as well as the formula of linear regression.

As a last test, I wanted to implement gradient descent myself, however, my method takes too long to converge and the values that are found are not correct compared to my other two methods. This is what my code looks like in python:

```
def mse(X, theta, Y):
    h_theta = X.dot(theta)
    return 1/(2*X.shape[0])*np.sum(np.square(h_theta-Y))

def gradient_descent_step(X, theta, Y, alpha):
    h_theta = X.dot(theta)
    difference = h_theta-Y.reshape(-1, 1)
    update = X.T.dot(difference)
    m_inverse = 1/X.shape[0]
    update = -alpha*m_inverse*update
    return theta + update

X = np.append(np.ones((boston.data.shape[0], 1)), boston.data, axis=1)
theta = np.ones((X.shape[1], 1))
print(theta.shape)
print(X.shape)
alpha = 0.0000001
for i in range(500000):
    #print("Cost in step " + str(i) + ": " + str(mse(X, theta, boston.target)))
    theta = gradient_descent_step(X, theta, boston.target, alpha)

print(theta)
print("Cost: " + str(mse(X, theta, boston.target)))
```

My learning rate is very small, because otherwise, the cost increases in each iteration. I do not see any mistake in my code, so I do not know what is wrong. I have not normalized the data, but my other two methods work fine without normalizing the data, so I think this one should too?

After running the above piece of code, I get a remaining cost of 31988.011713726573 which is too large.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `theta` the list/array of parameters?  If so, are you adding a column full of ones into `X` in order to have a bias term?  If `X` is just the data then you're likely missing a bias term.

Comment: Yes, theta are the list of parameters. I do add a column of ones (the first line after the gradient_descent_step function) so I have a bias term.

Comment: Try normalizing the data.  The closed-form solution naturally shouldn't matter, but gradient descent might well (and sklearn is calling scipy, which is using lapack functions).

Comment: @BenReiniger Thanks for your input. I tried normalizing and compared the results to the GradientDescent of scikit learn which resulted in about the same coefficients.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the alpha?